# Tweek the regex

Tags: regex

I'm very bad at regex.

The below expression does mostly what I need, but it requires the user to input "0.XX" for decimals, rather than allowing ".XX", without having to type the "0".

Could someone give me the heads up on this?

Thanks!

```
ValidationExpression="^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)?$"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{1,3}` means that the RE will allow 1 to 3 of the previous atom (digits `0-9`), so just change it to `{0,3}` to allow 0 to 3 digits preceding the decimal.

Comment: only a bit embarrassing.  One day I'll learn RegEx.  Honest. ;o)

Comment: @localman: Be aware that now the empty string is also acceptable input. As is a single dot. Do you want that?